# Invalid Object name error?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this stored procedure that import an excel file then by using queries it create the reports that I want then it export the tables that were created by them.

the problem is that when I import the excel file the rest of the code doesn't see the table that was imported and I have to refresh my database to see the imported table.

[image]

well as you can see the job that import the file works fine, but the rest of code can not see the table.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Try adding a USE statement and see if that works? and did you also try to select the table individually out side the sp?

Comment: @mfredy I have the USE statement in the top of my sp.but I need the select to be inside the procedure.

Comment: can you trying print the variable '@Return_value' and see if it has got a value?

Comment: What's on line 8 in the procedure?

Comment: @LukStorms from [dbo].['New LP']

Comment: to reference a table or view it's normally done without the quotes in the brackets. Does `dbo.[New LP]` exist?

Comment: @LukStorms when I refresh the database tables it shows.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the quotes?

Comment: @LukStorms the quotes is a part of the table name.

Comment: That's ... weird. But whatever. Still, you're asking to solve a problem in the code of a procedure that you don't show.  Unless some members of stackoverflow are gods, you can't expect omniscience from the community.

Comment: It must be `dbo.[New LP]` in your SP.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below method.

Inside the procedure ,change the TableName to 3 part as '[database name].dbo.[tablename].

Say if the table [New LP] is created in the database abc,change the table name inside the procedure as [abc].dbo.[New LP].

Comment: I added the database name and now it return this error:   'Staff.dbo.'New LP''

Comment: Cover your TableName with [ ] brackets and try again. Let me know if you are still getting the error.

Comment: But I just saw that the line that return the error is this:  ALTER PROCEDURE [Network].[Final_Result]

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting.. If include the sp in your question.

Comment: The error is exactly the same one in the photo. when I execute the procedure that error is what it returns.

Comment: Please, provide the SP ALTER or CREATE script. It is obvious some problem inside this SP.